# Git alias in worktree not working as expected in git 2.16

Tags: git

A Git alias that switches into a specific Git repository, then runs the provided Git command, i.e.:

```
[alias]
    repo1 = "!f() { cd /path/to/repo1 && git \"$@\" ; } ; f"
```

does not work with Git 2.16.2, if executed inside a Git worktree. It worked fine in Git 2.12.0.

Whatever Git command is passed to the alias gets executed in the original worktree directory, rather than in the intended destination directory.

Steps to reproduce:

```
$ mkdir -p /tmp/git
$ cd /tmp/git
$ mkdir repo1 repo2
$ cd repo1
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /private/tmp/git/repo1/.git/
$ touch foo
$ git add foo
$ git commit -m"git log should show this"
[master (root-commit) 6c366be] git log should show this
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 foo
$ cd ../repo2
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /private/tmp/git/repo2/.git/
$ touch bar
$ git add bar
$ git commit -m"git log should NOT show this"
[master (root-commit) 27f9a83] git log should NOT show this
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 bar
$ git branch new
$ mkdir ../repo2worktrees
$ git worktree add ../repo2worktrees/new new
Preparing ../repo2worktrees/new (identifier new)
HEAD is now at 27f9a83 git log should NOT show this

$ git config --global alias.cdg '!f() { cd /tmp/git/repo1 && git "$@" ; } ; f'

# From inside normal Git repo, works as expected:
$ git cdg log
commit 6c366be9188da3c8f9308ccfe1682c605ff6fed2 (HEAD -> master)
Author: msleigh 
Date:   Tue Jun 12 22:22:06 2018 +0100

    git log should show this

# From outside Git repo, works as expected:
$ cd .. ; git cdg log
commit 6c366be9188da3c8f9308ccfe1682c605ff6fed2 (HEAD -> master)
Author: msleigh 
Date:   Tue Jun 12 22:22:06 2018 +0100

    git log should show this

# From inside worktree:
$ cd repo2worktrees/new ; git cdg log
commit 27f9a83b7f62830b43277517b237e9b22cb9df9c (HEAD -> new, master)
Author: msleigh 
Date:   Tue Jun 12 22:22:42 2018 +0100

    git log should NOT show this
```

A Git bug? If so any ideas how I can re-write the aliases to achieve the right result?

---

**Update**

I should add that if I use `git -C <destination> <command>` in the alias, instead of `cd <destination> ; git <command>`, the effect is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not precisely a bug, depending on what you think of other things: it's likely related to a number of other `git worktree` and alias-related fixes between Git 2.12.0 and 2.16.0.  In particular, some operations need to know where the Git directory and work-tree "really are", so they will set the special environment variables that carry that information.  Without setting those things, *other* commands misbehave.

If `$GIT_DIR` and/or `$GIT_WORK_TREE` is/are set in the environment, that determines where the repository and work-tree reside.  Doing any `cd` doesn't *un*-set the environment variable; it persists into the sub-shell for the alias.

What you can do is override these yourself, setting or unsetting the environment variables or using the `--work-tree` and `--git-dir` options.  That is, instead of:

```
repo1 = "!f() { cd /path/to/repo1 && git \"$@\" ; } ; f"
```

you might define this as:

```
repo1 = "!f(){ git --git-dir=/path/to/repo1.git --work-tree=/path/to/repo1 \"$@\";}; f"
```

(I squished out some spaces here to make it fit better for StackOverflow) or:

```
repo1 = "!f() { unset GIT_DIR GIT_WORK_TREE; cd /path/to/repo1 && git \"$@\"; } ; f"
```